# Python: Reference to other projects in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, reference

In my Eclipse environment I have several projects. In one project I want to use a module from another project importing it by `from project1.module1 import class1`.
But when i execute the script i get:

> no module named project1.module1

Please help.

Comment: Do you have an empty \_\_init\_\_.py file in your project1 directory?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: @Gitarooman yes it has one